# How to extract the text from a file between two similar strings in linux?

Tags: linux, unix, sed

i Have a file that contains text as below

```
Jun  9 2014
some text...
Jun 10 2014
some text...
some text...
Jun 10 2014
some text...
Jun 10 2014
some text...
Jun 11 2014
some text...
Jun 12 2014
some text...
```

I have tried with sed command something like this:

```
sed /"Jun 10 2014"/,/"Jun 10 2014"/p file_name.txt
```

But this will give only the text between first and second string Jun 10 2014

I want to extract all the text between the 1st occurrence of the string Jun 10 2014 to the last occurrence of the same string Jun 10 2014, including the text followed by the last Jun 10 2014 up to the text Jun 11 2014.

Comment: What is the expected output for your supplied input file?

Comment: will `June 11 2014` always come after `Jun 10 2014` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the range from `Jun 10 2014` to `Jun 11 2014`, but do additional filtering inside:

```
$ sed -n '/Jun 10 2014/,/Jun 11 2014/ {/Jun 1[01] 2014/!p}' file_name.txt
some text...
some text...
some text...
some text...
```

Comment: But what if there is not data for `Jun 11` but `Jun 12`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` solution:

```
awk '/^Jun 10/ {f=1} /^Jun/ && !/^Jun 10/ {f=0} f && !/^Jun/' file
some text...
some text...
some text...
some text...
```

This prints from `Jun 10` until its no more `Jun 10`